# Specify the path to save a file

Tags: magento-1.9, module

I'm still learning magento and I have a custom module which will accept certain inputs and save those in an excel sheet. I wonder how I can tell my module to where the excel file should be saved.

I have googled a lot and found nothing except the programmatical way of saving an image.

A little help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are uploading your file from a controller.
If that's true, you can add this to the controller

```
protected function _uploadAndGetName($input, $destinationFolder, $data)
{
    try {
        if (isset($data[$input]['delete'])) {
            return '';
        } else {
            $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader($input);
            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
            $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
            $uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
            $result = $uploader->save($destinationFolder);
            return $result['file'];
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        if ($e->getCode() != Varien_File_Uploader::TMP_NAME_EMPTY) {
            throw $e;
        } else {
            if (isset($data[$input]['value'])) {
                return $data[$input]['value'];
            }
        }
    }
    return '';
}
```

Then you can use this method to upload the file where ever you want and get the name after upload like this:

```
$input = 'file'; //this is the name of the form file input
$destination = 'path/to/destination'; //where you want the file uploaded
$data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
$file = $this->_uploadAndGetName($input, $destination, $data);
```

Comment: thanks a lot... this is exactly what I was looking for.. :)